# Cannot launch specific applications on Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, windows-10, spyder

The problem is:
I cannot launch applications like Spyder, Glueviz, Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab from Anaconda.
I however can launch VS code but I suspect this is because I already had it previously installed.
However typing "jupyter notebook" or "jupyter lab" on the windows command prompt would launch it well, but this is not using Anaconda. I think this is because I have previously installed jupyter using pip.

First time I installed Anaconda, I checked the add to path option and a while later I had to uninstall it because I couldn't run python applications outside of anaconda. I checked my environment path variables and there are no references to Anaconda in it. So I guess this solution is out of the way.

This time when installing Anaconda, I made sure not to check the add to path option.

Sometimes, I would think this is an installation error, let's uninstall it then reinstall it, but that didn't work. I am using a freshly installed version of Anaconda now and the problem is persisting.

Here is an error that displays when I try to launch Spyder

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\saife\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in 
from spyder.app.start import main
File "C:\Users\saife\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\saife\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Hi, try this`pip install --upgrade pyzmq` .

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of pip, conda install -c anaconda "IDE you want"

Comment: I get "CondaValueError: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file"

Comment: sorry my bad, typo. just type the name of the IDE after that last anaconda without quotes obviously